# Regression of the replicated measures (on pooled individuals) of an outcome variable on an individually measured predictor variable

Tags: regression, variance, modeling, biostatistics, pooling

I keep running into the same kind of statistical/experimental problem and I still do not know how to deal with it properly.

In abstract terms my issue is to perform a regression of the replicated (not repeated) measures of an outcome variable on pooled individuals using an individually measured predictor variable, with a focus on accounting for the variance between the replicates of the group outcome and the variance between individual measurements in the predictor.

To describe it in more concrete terms, here is an experiment:
Let’s imagine that we have 15 populations of flies and that we measure the mass of each of 50 individuals from each population.
We then want to see if this is a good predictor of the dry matter content of the pupae. Therefore, we grow larvae for each population in 8 trays. We then measure the dry matter content for 100 pupae from each population and each tray crushed together. (Due to technical reasons we can only measure dry matter on a pooled group of 100 pupae.)
My issue is how to account for the variance in the individual measurements and the variance between the trays.

This experiment is only an example because I run into this issue quite often and sometimes with slight variations:

1. An extension of this problem is if the 8 trays are separated into 4 with substrate A and 4 with substrate B and that we want to also account for possible interactions between the population and the substrate.
2. In a different experiment, if the individuals from the pools are the same as the individuals form the individual measurement but, for some reason, there is no way to know which individual was in which pool (i.e., each replicate).

Answer (score 1):

Since the response is only measured at the group level, you need covariates at the group level also. So use the individual measurements for the group members to construct new variables, possibly

- sum of individual values
- standard deviation ...

That implies that your effective number of observations is the number of groups.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let say that I use the average of the individual values as a covariate, how do I still take into account the variance (or standard deviation) of the individual measurements? Maybe my understanding is wrong but a higher variance in the individual measurements should decrease my confidence in the estimations. And additionally, once I have averaged all my individual measures, how do I account for the variance in the response for each replication? Is it then correct to just re-use the same aggregated covariate value for each response replicate?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by *re-use the same aggregated covariate value for each response replicate*. For each group you only have the aggregated values, so there is only one observation by group. So how do you reuse values?

Comment: Ok, maybe the description was not so clear but what I mean with "the replicated (not repeated) measures of an outcome variable on pooled individuals" is that there are separate pools (or trays) from the same group and therefore several observations per group on the response side.